# Firebase Cloud Functions: not being called

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple firestore trigger defined as below:
**index.js**

```
const func = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addFriend = func.firestore
    .document("/requests/{userId}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const original = snap.data().original;

      // let toUID=original['sentRequests'];
      // let fromUID=userID;

      func.logger.log("context params", context.params, original);
      return snap.ref.set(original);

    });
```

However on deploying it using the command.

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I cannot see logs, which means the function is not being triggered.
**Note:**

1. I have verified 'requests/{userId}' to be a valid document path.
2. I have verified rules allow write.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the "not being called" problem but I saw a different kind of error. But first, I was able to make your code work with a security rule that only allows authorized users to add and update data on `requests`:

```
service cloud.firestore {  
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /requests/{userId} {
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

On a separate test app, I insert the data using the following code:

```
async function addData() {
  const data = {
    original: 'foobar',
  };
  
  const res = await db.collection('requests').add(data); // doc ID is auto-generated 

  console.log(`added ${JSON.stringify(data)} with doc ID ${res.id}`);
}
```

The `logger` part of your code works as intended however, `return snap.ref.set(original)` will cause an error because you're passing a String value in it instead of Object:

> Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

To solve this, you need to pass object containing the fields and values with which to update the snapshot. Using `set()` will override the snapshot. If you don't want this to happen, use `update()`:

```
return snap.ref.update({
  "newField" : original
});
```